# Getting all placeholders from file with pattern @{} using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get all the placeholders in a file which has a pattern @{}. I am trying to get hold of all variables but I am not able to define the pattern for the ending parentheses and also the whole word within. Below is my code so far

```
$SampleText = "I need all the variables with @{abc} @{def}
and @{xyz}"
$Pattern = '@{\w*'
$SampleText | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $Pattern 
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

Doing this I am getting only @{abc, @{def and @{xyz as outputs. I need the whole @{abc}, @{def} and @{xyz} to be obtained. I tried changing the $pattern with lot of variations and it's not helping

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more succinct solution (PSv3+):

```
 $SampleText | % { [regex]::Matches($_, '@\{\w+\}').Value }
```

Note that even you though you got away without `\`-escaping `{` and `}` in your specific regex, you should generally do so, because they are metacharacters used in quantifiers (e.g., `{2}` to specify a repeat count of 2).

`[regex]` is PowerShell's type accelerator for type `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`, which provides features beyond what the PowerShell's `-match` operator offers.

In this case, the static `Matches` method returns *all* matches of the specified regex in the input string, as `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` instances.
Each such instance records the matched string in its `.Value` property, so applying `.Value` to the entire collection of matches (which is of type `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection]`), the individual matches are returned as an array of strings.

Comment: Wow, this is just pure gold. Thank you so much. I do realize now I gotta explore more options and practice them.

Comment: @VKarthik: Thanks; while PowerShell offers a lot of high-level functionality, sometimes using .NET features directly either makes things simpler or enables you to do things PowerShell won't let you do directly. It's a testament to PowerShell's flexibility that that option is available.

Answer (score 0):

Aah, little more digging around. I figured it out. The pattern needs to be adjusted as shown below -

```
$Pattern = '@{\w*}'
```